# c# intersection two collections returns collection with intersected index and new field

Tags: c#, lambda, collections, intersection

I have two collections:

```
IEnumerable<int> data1 = new List<int> {101, 102, 103, 104};
IDictionary<int, int> data2 = new Dictionary<int, int> 
{
   { 101, 1 }, 
   { 104, 0 }
};
```

I want do to something like

`var newData = data2.intersect(data2, lambda expression)`;

`newData` should be a collection of `IEnumerable<int, bool>`

being the first field the intersection of `data1 == data2.Key` and the second field the evulation of `value == 1`

Comment: exactly I need a result with this data structure `IEnumerable<int, bool>`

Comment: Except that's not valid. Do you mean `IEnumerable<(int, bool)>` (i.e. an enumerable of value tuples)?

Comment: yes @ProgrammingLlama

Comment: the dictionary comes from a repository I don`t know exactly what does it contain beforehand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a join between both, which is like an intersection:

```
var query = from d1 in data1
            join d2 in data2 on d1 equals d2.Key
            select (Value: d1, Result: d2.Value == 1);
        
IEnumerable<(int Value, bool Result)> resultList = query.ToList();
```

The result list contains two items:

```
101 True
104 False
```